USB Audio Device cannot be selected but appears in USB-DEVICES
The device is a Maono Maonocaster C2 Neo. Ubuntu 24.04.
I can select the device for both input and output using Audacity when routed through the JACK server but I cannot use it for general system audio.
This is how it appears when listed with usb-devices.
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1235 ProdID=0003 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Maono
S:  Product=Maonocaster C2 Neo
S:  SerialNumber=P0RC05
C:  #Ifs= 5 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  64 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)

Is there a way to force Pulse to "see" this device and let me select as system in/out ?

Almost as quickly as I post my question I find a solution for an older version of Ubuntu.
Remove and purge both alsa-base AND pulseaudio, remove the user configuration for pulse, reinstall both, force a reload of alsa and then restart the machine.
Listing all sink devices now has my Neo appear with the bizarre name of RemoteSL + ZeroSL Analog Stereo.
sudo su
apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
exit
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/
sudo su
apt-get install alsa-base
apt-get install pulseaudio
alsa force-reload
shutdown -r now

